# Error using Limits class

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

Following is the code where Salesforce is showing error: "Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Limits"

```
if(updatedContacts.size() + Limits.getDMLRows() > Limits.getLimitsDMLRows()) {
        // show error about DML rows limit
}
```

Limits is an inbuilt class. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method is [getLimitDMLRows()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getLimitDMLRows) not `getLimitsDMLRows()` as you have in your code.

Comment: I had a double check on it but still missed it somehow. Thanks for pointing out!